# Python convert bytes to signed integer (wanna have a negative integer as a result)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggeling to convert a byte array (bytes) back to a singed integer. I found a lot of examples which are valid for having positive integers after the conversion but no working example how to handle a negative number.

```
#example for positive numbers is working fine    
data = I2C.read_i2c_block_data(I2CAddress, I2CRegister, 4)

result = 0

for b in data:
    result = result * 256 + int(b)
```

I am running python on a raspberry with python version 2.7.9.

It would be nice to get a basic algorithm for that.

My goal is to convert the byte array from variable data back to a negative number.

variable data has these items in its array:

```
[0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe7]
```

Target negative number is `-25` (which is obviously `0xe7`)

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide an example for `data` and what you expect `result` to be at the end?

Comment: #example for positive numbers is working fine    
data = I2C.read_i2c_block_data(I2CAddress, I2CRegister, 4)

result = 0

for b in data:
    result = result * 256 + int(b)



an arduino is sending a negative integer as a byte array over I2C.

In data variable the array looks like:
0xff
0xff
0xff
0xe7

this is the representation of -25 integer as a byte array.
So how can i convert that back using basic algorithm or existing methods which are supported in python 2.7.9

Comment: Side note: when manipulating binary data, we typically use binary operators like `<<`, `&` and `|` instead of arithmetic operators like `*` and `+`. Changing to these won't necessarily solve your current problem, but it is good to learn how to use these operators.

Comment: Side-note: Migrating to Python 3 would make this *much* simpler and *much* more efficient, thanks to [the `int.from_bytes` alternate constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) (which can interpret as signed or unsigned values).

Comment: Also note: If the bytes in question are encoded C type `int`s, the `struct` module is the way to handle this, e.g. `struct.unpack('>i', bytearray([0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe7]))[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you find the unsigned `result` using the above method, you can convert it to a signed integer:

```
max_int = 2**(8*len(data)-1)-1
result = result - (2 * (max_int + 1) if result > max_int else 0)
```